# RTL Languages support in android and resource qualifiers

Tags: android, localization, right-to-left

I read this sentence " Android 2.3 added support for right-to-left (RTL) languages"
and now I want to add RTL support to my app. But I do not know what is qualifiers to add to my layouts.

About res/values/strings.xml , I can named like this res/values-ar/strings.xml

I want to have different layout for RLT languages. I do not want to have just different strings , I also want different layout. What the layout folder name should look like ?

At this moment for the left to right languages it is named
res/lauyots/main.xml
but I do not know how to name it for RTL languages

Is this kind qualifier is present at all ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Silwek is right. This is his answer, I am merely putting it here because my answer has been marked as answered.

```
res/layout-ldltr/ (Left to Right, default value)
res/layout-ldrtl/ (Right to Left)
```

**Old Answer**

Check [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) and [Multiple Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), they give you idea about resource folders and qualifiers.

You can use locale specific resources and layout like this:

For language specific resources:

```
res/values/strings.xml
res/values-fr/strings.xml (French)
res/values-ja/strings.xml (Japanese)
```

For language specific layouts:

```
res/layout-fr/main.xml
res/layout-ar/main.xml
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that there is some qualifiers for rtl. Please taka a look on this if you know the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316160/multiple-screens-for-htc-desire-and-htc-sensation

Answer (score 16):

You can find **-ldrtl** and **-ldltr** qualifiers in [Providing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

```
res/layout-ldltr/ (Left to Right, default value)
res/layout-ldrtl/ (Right to Left)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using rtl with resources is not a correct approach .. you missed that Devices with RTL locale such Arabic,Hebrew, Persian ... usually enforce all apps ( even with english language only ) to use rtl as language direction and text direction... and here where its dangerous to use rtl in resources because **you will cause using your RTL layout for all languages for RTL Locale device.** Better to track languages.